# A specific sentence makes me confused on Singular and plural

Tags: singular-vs-plural, singular

> - a.1) John and Sam are friend.
> - a.2) John and Sam are friends.

Now if you say (a.2) is correct and (a.3) then what about (b.1),

> - b.1) John and Liza are couple.

Consider another example,

> - c.1) John and Sam both are smart.

I want to ask you about the correct rule for such sentence construction.

> If I made any grammatical mistake in the question then please mention it in comment

Comment: c1 is non-idiomatic (almost everyone says *John and Sam **are both** smart*). a1 and b1 are simply ungrammatical (b1 should be *...are **a** couple*). But what exactly are you confused about here?

Comment: This is just a comment about your grammar. In a few places, you made the grammatical mistake of leaving out a necessary article. "John and Liza are couple" is ungrammatical and should be replaced by "John and Liza are **a** couple." I would rephrase the last sentence as "if I made any grammatical mistake**s** in the question, please mention it in **the** comment**s**."

Comment: @ Siddhartha Sadhukhan it seems you have a problem with the complemet (the part coming after _be_ words here). Probably your confusion is _why in A1, we say friend**s** but in other sentences we don't use **s**_. Well, you should know that a _couple_ is a **noun** which means _2 people who are married_ so if you say couple**s** it mean 4 or even more people which is not what you mean here because you're talking about two people. In sentence C1, _smart_ is an **adjective** we don't normally add _s_ to an adjective to make it plural. So we say e.g. _they're tall_ instead of _they's tall**s**_.

Comment: @Yuri then what will be, (1) John and Sam are enemy. (2) John and Sam are enemies. where (2) is correct. Like "COUPLE" can you give some other examples

Comment: @ Siddhartha Sadhukhan _enemy_ is like _friend_: _they're enemies_. More examples? _they're basketball players/doctors/notebooks._ Notice all these are **nouns** refering to **one thing** or **person** before you add **s** to them and make them plural. More examples for words like _couple_? _They're a team/group/band/pack._ Notice here these **nouns** refers to **a group of people** or **things** not **one thing/person**. More examples like smart? _They're big/shiny/soft._ Notice these are adjectives and can describe **one thing/person**  or **a group of people/things** and don't take **s**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a.2 Is correct because friends is the plural when you are talking about 2 of them.

- John and Sam are hard workers.

b.1 Should be "John and Liza are a couple" because the word "couple" already means two, so it should not be pluralized unless you are talking about more than one couple.  Other words that already imply more than one are treated the same.

- They are a great group.
- John, Liza, and Anthony are a great trio.

c1. Is correct because you are using an adjective to describe them (so no pluralization is needed), which is different then using the noun "friend" to identify them.

- John and Liza are funny.
- John and Liza are entertaining.

Comment: can you put some example in this context?

Comment: i mean examples

Comment: Added some examples